# Python pandas dataframe why using double squared brackets

Tags: python, dataframe

Why does

```py
print(data["column"].shape)
```

print  `(1819,)` whereas

```py
print(data[["column"]].shape)
```

prints `(1819,1)`

Answer (score 3):

`data["column"]` returns a Pandas Series which is always always as shape (n,) i.e. it does not have columns just a single row always.

`data[["column"]]` returns a Pandas DataFrame which has shape (m, n)

If you want multiple columns in a dataframe you can use the double brackets as follows.

`data[["col1", "col2"]]`